# R - Geometric Distribition

Tags: r, geometric-distribution

Why

1. `pgeom(20,0.01,lower.tail = FALSE)`
2. `1-sum(dgeom(1:20,0.01))`

produce different results in R? The result should be the same (at least in theory), right?

Output:

`[1] 0.8097279
[1] 0.8197279`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  think you just forgot to account for 0. We can have zero of failures in a sequence of Bernoulli trials before a success occurs.

```
> (1-sum(dgeom(0:20,0.01))) == pgeom(20,0.01,lower.tail = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Oh, you are right... thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! And welcome to the CV community.